# Reusing a component in another component but changing button name (Angular 4+)?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a component (componentA) that is using another component (componentB) in its HTML. 
ComponentB has a button where the title is something else, but I would like to change the name of the button in ComponentA.

ComponentA uses componentB button to navigate to another page, but ComponentB has button that opens up a form. The navigation works and everything, but I would just like to change the name of the buttons when its on different page.

ComponentA.html

```
<div>
    <component-b (click)="buttonEdit()"></component-b>
</div>
```

ComponentA.ts

```
public buttonEdit(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/users']);
  }
```

ComponentB.html

```
<button (click)="openModal()">Add Users</button>
```

ComponentB.ts

```
 @Input() buttonEdit: () => void;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this
Component B.tmpl:

```
<button (click)="openModal()">{{buttonName}}</button>
```

Component B.ts:

```
@Input() buttonEdit: () => void;
@Input() buttonName: string = 'Add Users';
```

Component A.ts:

```
public buttonEdit(): void {
  this.router.navigate(['/users']);
}
public buttonName(): string {
  ...
  return buttonName;
}
```

component A.tmpl:

```
<div>
    <component-b (click)="buttonEdit()" [buttonName]="buttonName()"></component-b>
</div>
```

Comment: is there an easier way to do this in case I would like to fix its CSS in componentA?

Comment: You can use ngStyle

Comment: `<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':'green'}"></<div>` this is example

Comment: it didn't work...it still taking the componentA background color

Comment: No, you should receive backgroundColor from component A like buttonName

Comment: but I would like componentA to have different background color and componentB to have another color. How can I do that?

Comment: Plz take a look below answer

Comment: @AmirChristian could you pls create stackblitz for to understand.. ? I'm facing the same issue.. here i have reusable table with ADD | EDIT | Delete.. i want to navigate to corresponding page based button actions

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Component A.tmpl:

```
<div>
    <component-b (click)="buttonEdit()" [buttonName]="buttonName()" [backgroundColor]="backgroundColor()"></component-b>
</div>
```

Component A.ts:

```
public backgroundColor(): string {
  ...
  return backgroundColor;
}
```

Component B.tmpl:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color': backgroundColor}"></<div>
```

Component B.ts:

```
@Input() backgroundColor: string = 'green';
```